# How to create oracle view by a function

Tags: sql, oracle

**how to create oracle view by function**
 1. First create a type 'p_type'
 2. Create a table 'p_table' as 'p_type'
 3. A function with 'p_table' pipeline

```
create or replace type p_type as object (
    v_name varchar(400),
    d_date date,
    i_val number 
);

create or replace type p_table as table of p_type;

create or replace function get_info return p_table pipelined 
is
    c number;
begin
    c := 1;
    /*
        A is table and it has only one 'a' attribute
    */
    for i in (select * from A) loop
        pipe row( p_type(
                    v_name => SUBSTR(i.A, 1, 10),
                    d_date => sysdate,
                    i_val  => c
            ) );
        c := c + 1;
    end loop;
    return;
end;


CREATE VIEW vw_info AS 
    select * from table(get_info);
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  What is the problem?

Comment: I'd also probably suggest using more meaningful variable/table names.

Comment: Your code works for me on 12.1.0.2 Enterprise Edition.  Are you running into an error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: I think it's just a shared knowledge :)